# python redis lpush fails: insufficient buffer length

Tags: python, redis

I insert a relatively large number of keys into a redis server (about 1-2 million). The following two snippets are straight from the documentation, where the first uses single inserts, the second uses pipelining.

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
for i in keys:
    vals = [...] # some long list
    r.lpush(i, *vals)
```

-

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
pipe = r.pipeline()
for i in keys:
    vals = [...] # some long list
    pipe.lpush(i, *vals)
pipe.execute()
```

Both approaches fail, where the python error is

```
ConnectionError: Error 32 while writing to socket. Broken pipe.
```

where only the second approach also throws an error in the redis-server log:

```
 Closing client that reached max query buffer length [..]
```

Interestingly I only come across such errors since I am working with `lists`. A third version works flawlessly:

```
import redis
import pickle
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
pipe = r.pipeline()
for i in keys:
    vals = [...] # some long list
    pipe.set(i, pickle.dumps(vals))
pipe.execute()
```

But I want to switch to the redis lists, because on large lists the inverse (`pickle.loads`) is quite inefficient.

**Questions:** Am I missing something by using `lpush` or is the Broken pipe a common thing? Is it possible to configure the redis-server to allow larger buffer sizes (in my case, as python `dict` the data consumes about 10 - 15GB memory)?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `mset`.  I don't have quite as much data as you, but it's also a large number of keys, maybe on the order of thousands.